# How do I mount a network file system?

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I'm trying to mount a filesystem on a remote machine:

```
root@Wolf:/# mount -t nfs 192.168.0.131:/disc2 /temp
mount.nfs: mount system call failed
```

The error is delivered after a long pause.

I can ping the machine, etc. There are no networking issues.

`/temp` exists on the local machine.

`/disc2` exists on the remote machine with `/dev/sdb5` mounted there.

I read somewhere I need to `apt-get install nfs-kernel-server nfs-common portmap`, which I did perform on the remote machine (and then both just to be sure):

```
Package nfs-kernel-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  nfs-common
```

Okay, so `apt-get install nfs-common portmap` then:

```
Note, selecting 'rpcbind' instead of 'portmap'
nfs-common is already the newest version.
rpcbind is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So, erm, that's good then. Isn't it?

EDIT:
Didn't know about this, thanks dubu, but did a bit of reading, and created this file:

```
root@barnard:~# cat /etc/exports
/disc2/oldstuff1  192.168.0.0(rw)
/disc2/oldstuff2  192.168.0.0(rw)
/digex            192.168.0.0(r)
```

That's right I think. Isn't it?
[This page](https://wiki.debian.org/NFSServerSetup) told me to `/etc/init.d/portmap restart`, and since I've got `rpcbind` instead:

```
root@barnard:~# /etc/init.d/rpcbind restart
[ ok ] Stopping rpcbind daemon....
[ ok ] Starting rpcbind daemon....
```

So, that's working, then. Isn't it? The same page said to `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server reload`, but according to the apt-get message it's been superceded by `nfs-common` so:

```
root@barnard:~# /etc/init.d/nfs-common restart
[ ok ] Stopping NFS common utilities: idmapd statd.
[ ok ] Starting NFS common utilities: statd idmapd.
```

That sounds positive. So now then, on the client end:

```
root@Wolf:/# mount -t nfs 192.168.0.131:/disc2/digex /temp
mount.nfs: mount system call failed
```

Still no joy.

EDIT 2:

```
root@barnard:~# exportfs -ra
-bash: exportfs: command not found
root@barnard:~# which exportfs
root@barnard:~# find / -name "exportfs"
root@barnard:~#
```

Hmm. I read somewhere it is installed in `nfs-kernel-server`, but apt just won't let me install it, reporting that `the following packages replace it: nfs-common`, and `nfs-common is already the newest version.` ... *very deep breath* ...

Well, that's gotta be the culprit then. Until I can get this installed it can't possibly work. But how do I get it installed?

At some point in my sleep-deprived state last night I added some apt sources, but evidently didn't update it. This time when I did `apt-get update` a ton of things happened, lots of stuff downloaded and best of all:

```
Selecting previously unselected package nfs-kernel-server.
Setting up nfs-kernel-server (1:1.2.6-4) ...
Replacing config file /etc/exports with new version

Creating config file /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server with new version
[ ok ] Starting NFS common utilities: statd idmapd.
[warn] Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no exports. ... (warning).
```

That's fine, copied into `/etc/exports` the data from before, restarted the services, no better, restarted the entire machine just to make sure. But still no-go.

FINALLY:
After the success with apt-get, and a lot of detective work mostly involving `tail /var/log/syslog` (thanks for that MKaama - one to remember in future), and matching up all the relevant directories I finally got it working. All that remains now is a little tailoring and tidying-up.

I think I can manage it from here. Thank you all ever-so much for the help.

Comment: How did you configure NFS on the server? Show us your `/etc/exports` on the server.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Dubu. I've edited the text to include more info.

Comment: You could also try `/usr/sbin/exportfs`, `cat /proc/fs/nfsd/portlist`, `telnet localhost 2049`, `tail /var/log/syslog`, `cat /proc/fs/nfsd/pool_stats` on the server. The telnet connection reflects in syslog on my system.

Comment: `exportfs -ra` needs to be run to make sure nfs shares are exported properly

Comment: Thanks guys, with these clues I was able to get started properly. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

If your exports file on the remote system reads:

```
/disc2/oldstuff1  192.168.0.0(rw)
/disc2/oldstuff2  192.168.0.0(rw)
/digex            192.168.0.0(r)
```

then you should be issuing a

`mount -t nfs 192.168.0.131:/digex /temp`

and not

`mount -t nfs 192.168.0.131:/disc2/digex /temp`

Comment: Good point, thank you very much or spotting this.